# Loading OpenGL extensions with Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I've followed this article on using OpenGL extensions in Qt5 ([reference](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/)) and following the example code, I get the following error messages:
    undefined reference to

```
QOpenGLExtension_ARB_instanced_arrays::QOpenGLExtension_ARB_instanced_arrays()'
undefined reference to `QOpenGLExtension_ARB_instanced_arrays::initializeOpenGLFunctions()'
```

I've made sure that I have said extension through *m_context->hasExtension(..)*

Here's my code block (very similar to the article code):

```
assert(m_context->hasExtension(QByteArrayLiteral("GL_ARB_instanced_arrays")));
QOpenGLExtension_ARB_instanced_arrays* m_instanceFuncs = new QOpenGLExtension_ARB_instanced_arrays();
m_instanceFuncs->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
qDebug("extension loaded");
```

I'd assume the article would have mentioned other necessary steps.. I'm using Qt 5.3 on Windows 7 with a 4.3 Core context.

Comment: Maybe you compiled Qt 5.3 without support of QOpenGLExtension_ARB. For example you can use text search in Qt lib files and try to find mention of QOpenGLExtension_ARB_instanced_arrays. But it is not good method.

Comment: It's a good guess, but I don't think so. At least I see the header & implementation in Ming482_32\include\QtOpenGLExtensions\qtopenglextensions.h

Comment: Maybe it is bad method, but you can add qopenglextensions.cpp file to your project. You can find it in Qt sources.

Comment: Why do you need that extension? Isn't most of it in QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Compatibility anyway?

Comment: I added the qopenglextensions file to my own project, though it does not change anything unfortunately.
As for 4.3 Comp, I don't see it supporting the extension. It's besides the point however, I'd like to know that I can load extensions with Qt. ARB_instanced_arrays was just a test case.

Comment: I get the exact same issue when building on a Linux system with Qt 5.3

Comment: QOpenGLExtensions reside in another submodule than opengl, and so I had to enable it in the pro file like so:
QT += openglextensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QOpenGLExtensions reside in another submodule than opengl, and so I had to enable it in the pro file like so:

```
QT += openglextensions
```